# How to get ascendants and descendants from level with parent-child hierarchy?

Tags: mdx, olap, mondrian

I have a `location` dimension with level, which have parent-child hierachy. In a fact table i have a `location ID`. I am need to take a ascendants or descendants of this item.
I found only this way, but it is bad, because i have to know all route to this item.

```
select {[Measures].[some measure]} ON COLUMNS,
Ascendants([location.location].[03D718E0039347C891237433E17F61E8].[281774B2C7A046F4B7AD5B2B921126D6]) ON ROWS
from [location]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an error. I use web apps for geting results with Tabular format, wich dont give me full information. Using Multidimensional format resolve this problem.